# What's the difference between iTerm2 and Terminal on Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal

I have seen lots of programmers use iTerm2 instead the default Terminal on Mac. But, what's the difference between these two shell terminals on earth? For me, they are the same, I didn't see any difference except the different colors.

Answer (score 11):

As of Lion's release, a lot of the features iTerm2 boasted for a while now are finally matched in Terminal. plus a more consistent full screen (Lion) support.

Check out this apple stackexchange question
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25143/what-is-the-difference-between-iterm2-and-terminal

Answer (score 6):

http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/features

Comment: Full Screen, Resume, 256 colors, customizable ANSI colors, good drag-and-drop support, split panes (multiple views on a single terminal), Services for opening terminals for selected folders and pathnames in Finder and other applications, Services for looking up man pages, built-in man page lookup in the Help menu search field, Command-Double-Click to open URLs and man page references (for navigating man pages) as well as email addresses, New Remote Connection browses servers on the LAN and supports Bonjour, Window Groups, blurred backgrounds, background images, …oops! I'm out of space.